# What do people need to run my application?

Tags: c++, qt, distribution

I made a little app and built a release version. Now I want to upload it to my site. I have never done this before with Qt, so I'm unsure as to what I should include along with the binary.

How do I figure out which DLLs should be included with my app? And where do I get them? I'm running Windows, but I'd also like to know what I should do in case I want to release a Linux version.

Comment: For linux just give them the source and let them compile it.

Comment: @Falmarri:  Such an ideological view.  I'm sure you are well aware that this is often not possible.

Comment: @John: It depends from whose perspective you're looking at whether this is desirable or not =P

Comment: Well, some idealists say that all software on linux should be open and free.  But my perspective is that I'd prefer to earn a salary.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For windows:

You can use dependency walker to see what Qt libraries (or others) you should ship. This is the `depends.exe` executable that is included with Visual Studio, but you can download it separately from: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Load your app into that and it will list out all the modules it expects at runtime. You might also have to ship a Visual C++ Runtime Redistributable compatible with the compiler that you built the executable with (if it's VC++).

Do note that dependency walker does not account for things like Qt's plugins. An example of this would be the QtAssistant system (for help menu-type functionality), which as of Qt4 relies on Qt's sqlite functionality, which is typically built as a plugin (`qtsqlite4.dll` if I remember).

For Linux:

This is trickier because of wider disparities in Linux distributions. You can of course use the GNU build system if you want to ship source, but if you're shipping binaries, and want to support a variety of distros, you might do best to build packages for each platform you want to release on.

---

In my past, a company I worked for switched to using [`cmake`](http://www.cmake.org) and after setting up all the project and build files, used that to generate builds and packages for different OSes. On Windows, this meant hooking in with [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), and for Unix-like systems, cmake knows how to generate things like installable shell scripts. Definitely made life *much easier*.

---

Our QA department would test our software in virtual machine instances of our supported platforms, completely clean, and see if anything was missing.

Comment: depends.exe will get the static dependencies but not the dynamic ones (explicit calls to GetProcAddress). If there are dependencies on MSVCRT then that gets quite complex - you basically have to ship the redistributable. Can't you link statically rather than against Qt DLLs. Make distribution so much simpler.

Comment: Also, in my experience it pays to work this out correctly (by reading the manuals of the libraries) rather than reverse engineering which has a tendency to fail on the platform on which you did not test (or did not exist when you redistribute).

Comment: @David, I agree, and you can link statically to Qt's libraries, but I don't think that the prebuilt Qt libraries have static libs (only libs that link to the DLLs). To get real static libraries Pieter will have to build Qt from scratch, probably. I've never used they're prebuilts due to different settings I used to build my VC++ applications. As for shipping Qt and all those dependent libraries, there was definitely a lot of work in my team to sanitize the build system we 'inherited' by using cmake.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about DLLs, I assume it is about Windows.

Use [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see the DLL dependencies.

Or... take a clean system, with no dev tools installed, and put your executable, try to run it there, and see what DLLs are reported as necessary and inexistent. Put the DLLs near the executable.

Answer (score 0):

For a Linux version, you can either create platform targeted releases of installers for each Linux fork or you can let people compile from source. If your app is new, the only way you get exposure is supply people with readymade installers, the targeted installers. New users loathe compiling packages from source.

You can try debian (.deb) and redhat (.rpm) packages first. These two are extremely popular lines and will let you have a taste of things.